# using objective c runtime functions in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties, runtime

I want to get at the types of the properties of my objective C classes.  I see I can do this by using the runtime function property_getAttributes(property), which returns a C string like this:

```
    T@"UIColor",&,N,VsomeColor_   // ivar was UIColor* someColor_; property was (nonatomic, retain) UIColor* someColor;
```

or this:

```
    Tf,N,vfontSize_   // ivar was CGFloat fontsize_; property was (nonatomic) CGFloat fontSize;
```

I can then parse that string, i.e. look at the part after the initial T and before the following comma.

My question is -- is doing it this way likely to be stable?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: These all seem dangerously like implementation details...

Comment: OK, so is there a better way?

Comment: This is ok, but it begs the question: why do you need to do this? Runtime introspection like this is rarely necessary.

Comment: I want to write a general method that reads in ivars from a plist, and have it work for a general class.  I can also imagine that this would make archiving less painful than it currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`property_getAttributes` is part of the Objective-C runtime, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH1-SW1).

If you want to gain some kind of *introspection* about ObjC classes, it is the way to go. I don't think this is unstable, since the Objective-C runtime itself is quite stable. Furthermore there is an official guide (see link above) so you can trust it to be as stable as any other official Apple API.